# Prove that there does not exists $w\in V$ such that $||v-w||\le4$ and $||u-w||\le4$.

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

Suppose let $u,v\in V$ , $||u||=2$ and $||v||=11$ .Prove that there does not exists $w\in V$ such that $||v-w||\le4$ and $||u-w||\le4$.

how to prove this statement i think we prove by contradiction

i.e suppose there exists a   $w\in V$ such that $||v-w||\le4$ and $||u-w||\le4$.

i can't prove this contradiction .

Comment: But there does, right? For example, if $V = \mathbb R$ with norm $|\cdot|$  the absolute value , $u=2,v=10,w=6$, then this is contradicted.

Comment: A slightly more interesting result is that there's only *one* such vector $w$ (assuming an inner product space).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг,,............i don't understand

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг..i am editing now

Comment: Was the $10$ really a mistake in the problem statement (which originally said $11$)? The other way to make the problem work would have been to leave $\|v\|=10,$ but change one or both of the $\leq$ symbols to a strict inequality, $<.$

Comment: Now the question has been edited. It was about some time after it was posted. This completely changes the question, and now the answer is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use some triangle inequality.

If $u$ is distance $2$ from $0$ and $w$ is distance at most $4$ from $u$, then what is the maximum distance $w$ can be from $0$?

If $v$ is distance $11$ from $0$ and $w$ is distance at most $4$ from $v$, then what's the minimum distance $w$ can be from $0$?

Comment: ..the maximum distance is 6 abd 15

Comment: I was looking for a minimum in the second one! It should come out as $7$.

Comment: ....yes so then what next

Comment: So $\|w\|$ is at least $7$ and at most $6$. How many numbers do you know that fit that description?

Comment: ..no number is there

Comment: We have our contradiction. No such $w$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

think about the meaning of $\vec \ell_1=\vec u-\vec w$. this means that $\vec\ell$ is the vector that connect  $\vec u$ and $\vec w$. therefore given $\|\vec u\|=2$ and that $\sup\|\vec\ell_1\|=4$ we can calculate $\sup\|\vec w\|=6$. now let's look at it from $\vec v$. let's $\vec\ell_2=\vec v-\vec w.$ we can calculate $\inf\|\vec\ell_2\|$: if $\vec v=t\vec w$. now we know that $\|\vec v\|=11$ then $\inf\|\vec\ell_2\|=11-\sup\|\vec w\|=11-6=5$. and because $\inf\|\vec\ell_2\|=5>4$ we conclude that it is impossible.